# Как отобразить в браузере xml файл большого размера

Tags: java, xml, jsf, primefaces

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, кто сталкивался: с помощью чего можно отобразить в браузере xml файл на много тысяч строк? Отобразить в виде дерева с возможностью сворачивания узлов. Идеально было бы решение на JSF PrimeFaces, но буду рад любому решению.

Comment: если по отдельности. то считай тебе весь объем в память читать. пробуй запросить какое нибудь приложение на клиенте и открыть через это приложение, как делают с PDF-файлами. хотя думаю, что браузер справится с 200к строками

Comment: Все браузеры умеют отображать XML. Независимо от того, на каком фреймворке реализован фронтенд, можно просто открывать XML-файл в новой вкладке браузера.